# Newline character in cucumber scenario outline causing error

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, capybara

Working on a Cucumber feature here using a scenario outline where one of the values has a new line character like so:

```
Scenario Outline: Good stuff here
  Given I do some stuff
  Then I should see "<text>"

  Examples:
    | text                           |
    | text with a\nnewline character |
```

If I run this I get the error `765: unexpected token at text with a`.  If I run it with the newline and nothing after it like `text with a\n` it doesn't throw the error but for completeness I'd like to be able to check for the full string.  Is this a limitation of Cucumber scenarios or is there a work around?

Comment: What version of Gherkin are you using? (Also try \\n in case it's a string replacement issue into the `Then` line

Comment: Running Gherkin 5.1.  Your idea of trying the double backslash worked, can't believe I didn't try that.  If you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.  Much appreciated friend.

Comment: Done, and you're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - using `\\n` rather than just `\n` enables this to work, although from reading the cucumber/gherkin docs I'm guessing this is actually a bug in cucumber/gherkin so may break in a future release.